# How to load data from HDFS sequencefile in python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, sequencefile

I have a map reduce program running to read the HDFS file as below:

```
hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/contrib/streaming/hadoop-0.20.2-dev-streaming.jar -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1000  -file $homedir/mapper.py -mapper $homedir/mapper.py -file $homedir/reducer.py -reducer $homedir/reducer.py   -input /user/data/* -output /output/ 2> output.text
```

Anything to be confirm, the path /user/data/* has folders including files, /user/data/* will iterate all files under all subfolders right ?

The hdfs text file contains a JSON string for each line so the mapper read the file as below:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        object = json.loads(line)
```

But the owner of the HDFS changed the file from text into sequencefile. and I found the map reduce program output a lot of zero sized files, which probably means it did not successfully read the file from HDFS.

What should I change to code so that I can read from the sequencefile ?  I also have a HIVE external table to perform the aggregation and sorting based on that output of mapreduce, and the HIVE was STORED AS TEXTFILE before, should I change to STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/matteobertozzi/Hadoop/blob/master/python-hadoop/examples/SequenceFileReader.py)

Run below python file before your mapreduce job
input : your sequence file
output : your input to mapreduce

```
import sys

from hadoop.io import SequenceFile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print 'usage: SequenceFileReader <filename> <output>'
    else:
        reader = SequenceFile.Reader(sys.argv[1])

    key_class = reader.getKeyClass()
    value_class = reader.getValueClass()

    key = key_class()
    value = value_class()

    #reader.sync(4042)
    position = reader.getPosition()
    f = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
    while reader.next(key, value):
        f.write(value.toString()+'\n')
    reader.close()
    f.close()
```

You wont have to change you original python file now.

Comment: Thanks, should I change the hadoop stream job command to run this map reduce python script ?  The first code block I pasted.

Comment: you won't have to change the job submission command if your input dir is same. You will have to change your mapper.py

Comment: Thanks. I used the hadoop stream for processing, and mapper reads from the stdint, but your code read from the file directly (reader = SequenceFile.Reader("your_file_path")
) in the code. How to read the sequencefile from the stdin ?

Comment: I saw some posts are saying that add this into the command running hadoop job. -inputformat SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat

Comment: Thanks very much for your script to turn sequencefile into text string so that I can make my code work as before.  But the output of this file is in local disk but not HDFS right ? My hadoop mapreduce takes the input from HDFS.  Also, should I enabled the argument ?  -inputformat SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat

Comment: how were you getting your files into HDFS previously? if you are using oozie, you can use fs action to do so. or if you are using cron you can put the hadoop fs -put command in cron. you can even start a flume agent with spooling source

Comment: It is just not working. I tried to add the argument that everyone else said it is working for them, but not for me. and the code you provided failed at "from hadoop.io import SequenceFile" no modeule for hadoop.io.

Comment: you have to setup the hadoop.io from the [link](https://github.com/matteobertozzi/Hadoop/tree/master/python-hadoop)

Comment: They use camus job to dump into HDFS, but my program works fine before, and it is not working after they switch from text to sequencefile.